# Counting number of occurrences in a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, count

I need to return a dictionary that counts the number of times each letter in a predetermined list occurs. The problem is that I need to count both Upper and Lower case letters as the same, so I can't use .lower or .upper.

So, for example, "This is a Python string" should return {'t':3} if "t" is the letter being searched for.

Here is what I have so far...

```
def countLetters(fullText, letters):
    countDict = {i:0 for i in letters}
    lowerString = fullText.lower()
    for i in lowerString:
        if i in letters:
            countDict[i] += 1

    return countDict
```

Where 'letters' is the condition and fullText is the string I am searching.

The obvious issue here is that if the test is "T" rather than "t", my code won't return anything Sorry for any errors in my terminology, I am pretty new to this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You said you can't use `.lower`, why are you using it anyway?

Comment: collections standard library offers Counter class just for that

Comment: The loop should be `for i in lowerString:`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is with this code. Can you please show a [mre]?

Comment: I used .lower because he didn't clarify the first time that we arent supposed to use it. He is giving us the problem again with the additional condition of checking capitals this time to make sure we do not use .lower or .upper

Answer (score 1):

To ignore capitalization, you need to input =
**input = input.lower ()**
.Lists all characters of the input text using list operations.
It can also be used as a word counter if you scan the space character.

```
input = "Batuq batuq BatuQ" # Reads all inputs up to the EOF character

input = input.replace('-',' ')#Replace (-, + .etc) expressions with a space character.
input = input.replace('.','')
input = input.replace(',','')
input = input.replace("`",'')
input = input.replace("'",'')

#input= input.split(' ') #if you use it, it will sort by the most repetitive words
dictionary = dict()
count = 0
for word in input:
    dictionary[word] = input.count(word)
    
print(dictionary)

#Writes the 5 most repetitive characters
for k in sorted(dictionary,key=dictionary.get,reverse=True)[:5]:
    print(k,dictionary[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over the wrong string. You need to loop over `lowerString`, not `fullString`, so you ignore the case when counting.

It's also more efficient to do `if i in countDict` than `if i in letter`.

```
def countLetters(fullText, letters):
    countDict = {i.lower():0 for i in letters}
    lowerString = fullText.lower()
    for i in lowerString:
        if i in countDict:
            countDict[i] += 1

    return countDict
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried that but the problem is that when the test is "T", it does not return anything. Because of the .lower it seems to only take in lower case tests. That is where I am lost, I cannot think of a way to test for both lower and upper case as the same letter

Comment: Also use `.lower()` on `letters`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is simply duplicate the dict with both upper and lowercase like so:

```py
def countLetters(fullText, letters):
    countDict = {}
    for i in letters:
        countDict[i.upper()]=0
        countDict[i.lower()]=0
    lowerString = fullText.lower()
    letters = letters.lower()
    for i in lowerString:
        if i in letters:
            countDict[i] += 1
            if (i!=i.upper()):
                countDict[i.upper()] +=1

    return countDict
print(countLetters("This is a Python string", "TxZY"))
```

Now some things you can also do is loop over the original string and change `countDict[i] += 1` to `countDict[i.lower()] +=1`

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need to accomplish, but it is returning Capitals and Lower case letters separately in the dictionary, I need to count them as the same letter. {'A': 45, 'a': 45, 'E': 44, 'e': 44, 'I': 32, 'i': 32, 'O': 29, 'o': 29, 'U': 12, 'u': 12}

Comment: This should actually achieve what you are asking for. Although they are "separate" they have the same value.

Comment: It does in theory, but one of the tests is the length of the dictionary, so it can only return the specific value that is being asked for. So for the first test, 'aeiou', it can only return those five results. If I return capitals and lower case I fail the test

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work that handles both case sensitive letter counts and non case sensitive counts?

```
from typing import List

def count_letters(
    input_str: str,
    letters: List[str],
    count_case_sensitive: bool=True
):
    """
    count_letters consumes a list of letters and an input string
    and returns a dictionary of counts by letter. 
    """
    if count_case_sensitive is False:
        input_str = input_str.lower()
        letters = list(set(map(lambda x: x.lower(), letters)))
    # dict comprehension - build your dict in one line
    # Tutorial on dict comprehensions: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension
    counts = {letter: input_str.count(letter) for letter in letters}
 
    return counts

# define function inputs    
letters = ['t', 'a', 'z', 'T']
string = 'this is an example with sTrings and zebras and Zoos'

# case sensitive
count_letters(
    string,
    letters,
    count_case_sensitive=True
)
# {'t': 2, 'a': 5, 'z': 1, 'T': 1}

# not case sensitive
count_letters(
    string,
    letters,
    count_case_sensitive=False
)
# {'a': 5, 'z': 2, 't': 3} # notice input T is now just t in dictionary of counts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it - like this:

```
def count_letters(fullText, letters):
    countDict = {i: 0 for i in letters}
    lowerString = fullText.lower()
    for i in lowerString:
        if i in letters:
            countDict[i] += 1
    return countDict

test = "This is a Python string."
print(count_letters(test, 't')) #Output: 3
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped when I originally posted the question. I was messing with it beforehand to try to get it to work and changed my code. That is the code that I originally turned in, the problem is that when the test is "T", it does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

Use the Counter from the collections module

```
from collections import Counter
input = "Batuq batuq BatuQ"
bow=input.split(' ')
results=Counter(bow)
print(results)
```

output:
Counter({'Batuq': 1, 'batuq': 1, 'BatuQ': 1})